# How frequently does Yodlee update account transaction data?

Tags: yodlee

I can't figure out what are the guidelines for when transaction data is updated on Yodlee.  For bank accounts (checking, savings), how frequently does Yodlee go back to the bank to get timely data?  I tested with my own bank, and the balance and transaction data can be out of sync for a day or more.

Also wondering if the update timelines are consistent across all banks or if they are on different update cycles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please check our Refresh Policy-

> https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Platform_Overview/Refresh_Policy

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik